# Why are the Magog so poorly equipped?

Tags: andromeda

Why don't the Magog use ranged weapons, or at least equip themselves with basic armor?

Since they have space ships, it's not due to lack of technology. In fact, in the episode *Its Hour Come ‘Round at Last*, one Magog who identifies himself as Bloodmist is decked out in armor and a weapon, yet all of his "soldiers" are naked and weaponless, and as a result, get "plowed down en masse" when advancing towards the Andromeda crew armed with ranged weapons.

One would assume that a Magog attacking party (as opposed to parties that just scavenge already attacked settlements) would at least be equipped enough to handle carrying out their attack.

Comment: Not canon, but logically speaking it may be either cultural (True Celtic warrior disdains armor! True Samurai don't use guns!); or even societal (a way to thin down the # of Magog)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was never really mentioned in canon so this is surmise.

There are trillions of Magog; the amount of resources and effort it would take to give all of them even the most rudimentary of equipment just wouldn't be worth it to keep the sub-sentient soldiers alive for an extra foot of gained ground, not when you can just send in two more soldiers to gain that foothold anyway and eat the soldiers that didn't live through the fight.

If I remember correctly, the intelligent caste Magog always had weapons and armor whenever they were shown.

Comment: I always thought similar, comparing them to Star Trek's Borg (although those got personal shields after all). But at the same time the Magog are more effective: One fallen enemy can produce several new Magog (rather than just one drone).

Comment: I was going to compare them to the Posleen in the Legacy of the Aldenata books by John Ringo but I didnt feel like explaining the reference of course the Posleen did use guns